# There is no implicit reference conversion from ApplicationUser to IdentityUser

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I am trying to customize some ASP.NET Identity Core classes which use Generics.

**My ApplicationUser class:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>//, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationRole, ApplicationUserLogin> 
{
    public ApplicationUser() {  }
}
```

**My ApplicationUserStore class:**

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, Guid> 
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext ctx, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) : base(ctx, describer)
    {

    }
}
```

**Error message is:**

> 'AspDotNetCoreFullFramework.Identity.**ApplicationUser**`1[System.Guid]',
>   on`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`8[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken]'
>   **violates the constraint of type parameter 'TUser'**

Now, when I go to the .NET implementation of UserStore (Base class):

> public class UserStore<TUser, TRole, TContext, TKey> :
>   UserStore<TUser, TRole, TContext, TKey,
>   IdentityUserClaim<TKey>, IdentityUserRole<TKey>,
>   IdentityUserLogin<TKey>, IdentityUserToken<TKey>>
>           **where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey>**
>             ...
>           **where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>**
>       {

I can see that ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser<GUID>. 
This constraint is fulfilled.
TKey is GUID which implements IEquatable<GUID>. 
This constraint is also fulfilled.

So what is the problem?

Comment: Or point me to a reference regarding this problem..

Comment: what it exactly you are trying to do in regards to Identity, can you explain that a little bit more in detail.. I think this may help others point you into taking a different approach..

Comment: I just want to implement the ASP.NET Identity API as customizable as possible, in order to have it available as an template for future projects.
Later I can have a look at it, without much exploration effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the GUID to

```
IdentityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext,Guid>();
```

as mentioned in this [post](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/829) solved the problem.

Comment: Where do you add this? Startup.cs?

Comment: Under ConfigureServices I guess, long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

For those running into this error while creating a UserStore for testing: `There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ApplicationUser' to 'IdentityUser<string>'`, make sure your UserStore's type argument specifies the key type. Example below where `AppUser : IdentityUser<Guid>`:

```cs
new UserStore<AppUser, AppRole, AppDbContext, Guid>(appDbContent); // Guid is important
```

This question was the first that came up while searching. It is simple in hindsight but we got stuck trying to instantiate a UserStore like below. Hopefully this saves someone time in the future.

```cs
new UserStore<AppUser>(appDbContent);
```