# There is no implicit reference conversion from ApplicationUser to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to experiment and pass a custom IdentityUser on UserStore on it's generic argument.
So I inherited the IdentityUser and implement all the required interface with it's required generic argument.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<AppUser>(); //This is line that's triggering the error. AppUser has inherited all IdentityUser requirements, but I am not sure what I am missing here.
    }
}
```

AppUser has the following implementations:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int, AppLogin, AppRole, AppClaim>
{

}

public class AppLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
{

}

public class AppRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{

}

public class AppClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int>
{

}
```

But the problem is, it is not building successfully because of this error:

> Error CS0311  The type 'CustomIdentity.AppUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserStore'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'CustomIdentity.AppUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser'.

I have checked this post: [There is no implicit reference conversion from ApplicationUser to IdentityUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172807/there-is-no-implicit-reference-conversion-from-applicationuser-to-identityuser) but it's IdentityUser is not the customize as I am doing on my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer, I just missed out the definition, and having a keen eye on Intellisense works on this kind of situation:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<AppUser, AppRole, int, AppLogin, AppUserRole, AppClaim>(new MyDbContext(""));
```

And here are the definition of the classes:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int, AppLogin, AppUserRole, AppClaim>
{}

public class AppLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
{}

public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{}

public class AppClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int>
{}

public class AppRole : IdentityRole<int, AppUserRole>
{}
```

This is just an over simplified explanation and code but this will compile and you will get the idea on how to customize it. But in a simple way, you can do this on couple of lines, since this below code is the first override definition.

```
var userStoreSimplified = new UserStore<AppUserSimplified>();
```

Class definition:

```
public class AppUserSimplified : IdentityUser
{}
```